# React Native WebView onMessage stopped working in latest Chome Android build

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I have an app that uses web views to render forum posts in html. I've injected script to calculate the height of these web views after the content is loaded.

This has worked fine until the end of October 2018 and seems to be related to a recent update of Chrome.

I can still see that my scripts in the web views run and calculates the height. These use window.postMessage. But in the react native side the onMessage of the web view never gets the message.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the error. The problem seems to be that the signature for Chromes native postMessage method and the version that React Native replaces it with are the same now, so the common fix to check if `window.postMessage.length === 1` to know when RN is ready does not work. My solution was to check if `typeof window.originalPostMessage === 'undefined'` instead. When originalPostMessage is set, RN is ready.